# Unable clone repository using VSTS plugin in IntelliJ installed in linux Azure VM

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, azure-virtual-machine

1.Imported repository https://github.com/nwcadence/MyShuttle2.git in Azure.
2.Created a linux VM in Azure.
3.Installed IntellJ
4.Installed Microsoft Teams plugin and tried to clone the git repository from my Azure account to Intellij.
5.It was able to list the repository post entering my Microsoft credentials.
6.But when i clone the repository it again ask me for Microsoft credentials and says invalid credentials

Please let me know what is the issues

Answer (score 0):

I was in contact with the IntelliJ team this was very helpful hope it can help you too

> To authenticate to Azure you need to use Personal Access Tokens
>   instead of the password - see
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops
>
> Git does not prompt you on the command line likely because there is
>   git credential helper. IDE calls git with a flag not to use helper -
>   to make sure passwords are handles on the IDE side.
>
> If you want IDE to use helper as well - this can be disabled by going
>   to Help - Find Action - Registry.. and unchecking
>   `git.reset.credential.helper`